# Script to search inside non-root and tmp directories

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script:

```
egrep -R -s -c '([^0-9a-zA-Z_-]|^)(5[1-5][0-9]{2}( |-|)([0-9]{4})( |-|)([0-9]{4})( |-|)([0-9]{4}))([^0-9a-zA-Z_-]|$)' $searchpath | egrep '\:[^0]' > $logfilename
```

It needs to be modified to search only `/home` non-root and `/tmp` directories.

```
Home directories (off root)
Temp directories (off root listed as tmp)
```

*Websphere logs: Getting Specs for these logs

*Apache logs: Getting Specs for these logs

The output file should include the server name.    The search results should be empty, please create a log file, showing start, stop time and server name, no records found.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework.

If the paths to the (/tmp) directories (including their name) to be searched do not contain whitespace (which is quite probable) and assuming that all home directories are in /home and that nothing except for home directories is there then $searchpath can be replaced by pattern matching and (for the /tmp owner check) a find call:

```
... /home/* $(find /tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -user root) | egrep ...
```